# Как вывести числа с одинаковым знаком в списке?

Tags: python, алгоритм, list

Дан список чисел. Если в нем есть два соседних элемента одного знака, выведите эти числа. Если соседних элементов одного знака нет — не выводите ничего. Если таких пар соседей несколько — выведите первую пару.

Задача [здесь](http://pythontutor.ru/lessons/lists/problems/same_sign_neighbours/).

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
res = []
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    if (a[i] > 0 and a[i+1] > 0) or (a[i] < 0 and a[i+1] < 0):
        res.append(a[i])
        res.append(a[i+1])
print(res[0], res[1])
```

Делал элементарно. Обход списка, добавление в конец нового списка двух соседних элементов с одним знаком. Вывод только первых двух элементов нового списка, на случай, если таких пар окажется несколько. Проходит все тесты, кроме тех, где **Если соседних элементов одного знака нет — не выводите ничего.**

Что конкретно означает "ничего не выводить"?

У меня итак выводится на экран только в том случае, если есть хотя бы два соседних элемента, подходящих условиям.

Comment: `(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)` - какие из этих пар считаются числами одного знака? Какие нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

команда print у вас в самом конце вызывается в любом случае вне зависимости от условий. Если соседних элементов одного знака не будет, res будет пустым списком и во время вызова print произойдёт исключение IndexError. Чтобы понять эту ситуацию напишите в консольке:

```
>>> l = []
>>> print l[0]
```

Нельзя же взять первый элементов из списка где элементов нет. Поэтому перед вызовом команды print наложите условие на то, что res не пуст. А вообще существует более оптимальное решение. Но это уже совсем другой разговор:)

Comment: какая глупая ошибка была. Перед принтом я просто добавил if len(res) > 0 Спасибо! А можно другое решение тоже? В целях повышения образованности.

Comment: Кстати проверять список на пустоту можно просто условием `if res`. А по поводу другого решения скажу вот что. Вам же не обязательно хранить все пары чисел одного знака, достаточно только первой попавшейся. Как её найдёте, напечатайте её и сделайте break. Такое решение как раз и написано в другом ответе.

Answer (score 5):

Вот еще один из многих возможных вариантов:

```
l = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

for i in range(1, len(l)):
    if l[i-1] * l[i] > 0:
        print(l[i-1], l[i])
        break
```

Comment: умножение чисел с одинаковыми или разными знаками...просто до гениальности...

Comment: Пара `0, 0` не будет выдана.

Answer (score 0):

Вот программа выводит первую пару чисел одного знака, а при отсутствии такой пары ничего не выводит

```
s=input().split()
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    if int(s[i])*int(s[i+1])>=0:
        ans=s[i],s[i+1]
        ans=' '.join(map(str,ans))
        print(ans)
        break
else:
    print=''
```